# Angular2 can't use ngModel in form repeated by ngFor

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular2-ngmodel

How can I use ngModel for inputs across multiple forms that's repeated by ngFor?

Angular2 gives me error when I'm trying to do so.

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"
```

Example block of problematic code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <form name="itemForm">
        {{item.name}}<input [(ngModel)]="item.name">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/YNZiCBeyqJoxO5ox5nlC?p=preview

If I remove the form tag, it all run without problem, but I need it so I can use enter key on all input to update corresponding data in their own form.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Bx0zT8F0wENJ2NMZqRAy?p=preview. The `name` attribute was missing though.

Comment: Weird now that the plunker doesn't throw error the second time I opened it. My actual code still gave me the error, though it's already solved. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, it's your plunkr that works somehow by adding name attribute to the input tag.

Comment: Adding the name **or** `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` is required. But without the `name` I also got a different error than the one you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ngModel` is used within a form tag, either the `name` attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in `ngModelOptions`.

Below will work without any error :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <form name="itemForm">
    {{item.name}}<input [(ngModel)]="item.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `name` attribute to form `input` field would make more sense, rather than saying it as `standalone`

Comment: I tend to set the `name` attribute of the `input` field as well

Comment: From Angular documentation (https://angular.io/guide/forms): "Defining a name attribute is a requirement when using [(ngModel)] in combination with a form."

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ranakrunal9 you can use a **unique name** attribute for your input. Here the code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let index=index">
    <form name="itemForm">
        {{item.name}}<input [(ngModel)]="item.name" name={{index}}>
    </form>
</div>
```